# What is the geometric interpretation of Ito's Lemma?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis, geometric-interpretation

I've been studying Ito's Lemma for 1D case with 1D Brownian Motion. Here's the lemma just to remember:

$$dX_t=\big(\frac{\partial g}{\partial t}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}|_{x=B_t}\big)dt+\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}|_{x=B_t}dB_t$$

where $X_t=g(t,x)|_{x=B_t}$.

I know the extra term $\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}|_{x=B_t}dt$ comes from quadratic variation of Brownian Motion but does it have a geometric interpretation on its own?

Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2049548/121348)